# Outbound port for SQL Request

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, security, iis, port

I am connecting an ASP.Net Application to a SQL Server database behind a firewall.  I know that by default, communications from an IIS Web Server to the SQL Server go into port 1433/4.

However, the outbound port on the Web Server seems to be random in the range 1024-65535, as per the Microsoft guidance [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269882).

There are also some comments [here](https://superuser.com/questions/300648/sql-server-ports), but they don't answer the outbound port question.

Is there a way of restricting that so that firewall can only allow one or a small range of outbound ports?  AM I right in thinking the issue is in IIS (as the originator).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling 1433/4 will be enough, because IIS is connecting to SQL. There is not connection from SQL to IIS. The only thing you must rember is to preserve session on load balancer/firewall